# Why is $(1,1,...)$ an extreme point of a closed unit ball in $c$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Why is $(1,1,...)$ an extreme point of a closed unit ball in $c$ (the space of all convergent sequences with sup norm)?

Suppose on the contrary that $(1,1,...)= t (x_n)+(1-t) (y_n)$ for some $t$ in $(0,1)$ and $(x_n)\ne (y_n)\in c$.
Then, $tx_n+(1-t)y_n=1$ for all $n$, so $t x+(1-t)y=1$, where $x_n\to x, y_n\to y$.

How do I get a contradiction from here to conclude that $(1,1,...)$ is indeed an extreme point?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475323/extreme-points-of-the-closed-unit-ball-in-space-of-convergent-sequences but it does not explain why $x_n=y_n$.

Comment: What can you conclude from $1 =tx_n+(1-t)y_n \leq t(1)+(1-t)(1)=1$?

Comment: @geetha290krm: I don't understand how that helps. I think nothing can be concluded from here.

Comment: It implies $x_n=y_n=1$. No need to use limits of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Can you please explain how? I don't yet understand how. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are talking of "*a* closed unit ball", may be you did not think deeply enough about what *the*  closed unit ball of $c$ is.

Comment: @AnneBauval: yeah, I just thought that $\|(x_n)\|\le 1$, which is true but somehow didn't think that $x_n\le |x_n|\le \sup_n |x_n|=\|(x_n)\|$ :(. Of course, this assumes that everything is real valued here.

Comment: Note that if everything is complex valued, the result still holds, with nearly the same argument as in @geetha290krm 's answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval: yes, noted. I added that bit about real valued in my last comment so that  $x_n\le |x_n|$ makes sense in the comment. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1 =tx_n+(1-t)y_n \leq t(1)+(1-t)(1)=1$. If $x_n<1$ or $y_n<1$ then we get $1 =tx_n+(1-t)y_n < t(1)+(1-t)(1)=1$ or $1<1$ which is a contradiction. Hence, the only possibility is $x_n=y_n=1$ for all $n$.

As pointed out by Anne Bauval the conclusion holds even for complex sequences. [If $|c|\leq 1$ and $\Re c=1$ then $\Im c=0$ necessarily, so $c=1$].

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot :-).